# Spring boot integration tests with different profiles

Tags: spring-boot

I have two integration tests:
test1:

```
@Rollback(false)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = {Application.class, Config.class},
        webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles( "pr1")
public class Test1 {

}
```

test2:

```
@Rollback(false)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = {Application.class, Config.class},
        webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles( "pr2")
public class Test2 {

}
```

When I run all the tests together, the test 2 is using the context of test 1, which couse the test to fail.
From logs I can see that two application contexts are created for each profile.

Comment: How can you see that two contexts are created?

Comment: I can see in logs that for each test the new spring boot application is started

Comment: Sure but this doesn't mean that the context is not shared

Comment: yes, also I can see that two application contexts with different keys are retrieved
Retrieved ApplicationContext [1214118601]
Retrieved ApplicationContext [1356799609]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fully separate the test contexts you must use @DirtiesContext

```
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest
void Test {
...
}
```

Read more about that configuration: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dirtiescontext

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but I need to reuse application context, not to recreate it for each test, as there will be more tests, for ex, profile 1 will have 9 tests, and profile 2 will have 5 tests.